# How can I change super-minor number of a software raid array meta 1.2?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

I had a double failure while I was away on the holidays of my array. As I was saving the data, I created a new array on a new drive has /dev/md1 and copied the info from my almost failed remaing HD array of /dev/md0.

The original data was on an array listed created as /dev/md0, which I prefer.

How can I change my minor number of the raid back to /dev/md0 on the superblocks? When it boots, it is recognized as /dev/md1.

I have read forums and tried various thing like updating assembling the array in this fashion to try to rewrite the superblock to no avail:

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --super-minor=0 --uuid=c35876ca:13e90c31:dc40c61c:eccfa279
```

Current array info:

```
dell-desktop ~ # mdadm -Es
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=c35876ca:13e90c31:dc40c61c:eccfa279 name=dell-desktop:1

dell-desktop ~ # mdadm -E /dev/sdb6
/dev/sdb6:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : c35876ca:13e90c31:dc40c61c:eccfa279
           Name : dell-desktop:1  (local to host dell-desktop)
  Creation Time : Mon Jan  6 19:44:05 2014
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1898729472 (905.38 GiB 972.15 GB)
     Array Size : 949364544 (905.38 GiB 972.15 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1898729088 (905.38 GiB 972.15 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 521142b5:2385b1b6:08f36e23:be4ae276

    Update Time : Tue Jan  7 13:57:21 2014
       Checksum : 19503e2a - correct
         Events : 575


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)

dell-desktop ~ # cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md1 : active raid1 sda6[0] sdb6[2]
      949364544 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Any help is kindly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just fix the mdadm.conf line and assemble it. Reboot might be necessary but i don't think so.

Comment: I had already done that, but am looking for a way to reflect that in the superblock.

This is what I did changing
    ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=c35876ca:13e90c31:dc40c61c:eccfa279 name=dell-desktop:1

to

ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 UUID=c35876ca:13e90c31:dc40c61c:eccfa279 name=dell-desktop:1

Comment: this depends on metadata format. If it is 0.9 or 1.0 it can be changed using the info here http://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&m=130895284716309&w=2

You will basically recreate the superblock with new info but all params must be specified. Some usefull info can be hound in https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info. I was hoping for something less drastic as could be done on the 0.9 metadata. As in the OP, this metadata is 1.2. I'm fearful of running create again just to change the superblocks as I don't want to do anything to risk data loss even using the --assume-clean flag. I'll just keep with my original fix in mdadm.conf. Thanks for the info.